# Failed to create new project in android studio 0.2.3

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After I updated form 0.2.2 to 0.2.3,  I create new project failed.
Error message is below:
下午 08:51:58 Gradle 'NotifyViaGoogleMapsProject' project refresh failed:
            The SDK directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin\Program Files (x86)Androidandroid-studiosdk' does not exist.
            Build file 'F:\AndroidStudioDevelop\NotifyViaGoogleMapsProject\NotifyViaGoogleMaps\build.gradle' line: 9

NotifyViaGoogleMapsProject is my project name,and my android studio is install in default path(C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio), there has no same error in 0.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the problem.

Open '*local.properties*' in your project using a text editor.

```
sdk.dir=..\\sdk
```

Save and Close

Now Import your project into  Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the SDK folder you mention exists - I'm not sure if it is a typo or not but the path you specified is a bit weird - it should be

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk`

On the menu go to `File` -> `Project Structure`, then choose `SDKs` under `Platform Settings`. Check that the path for the Android Platform you use is correct, and if not, change it to the correct path. Also make sure that the `Project` is set to use the correct Android Platform.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPOOi.png

The SDK is correct in Platform Settings, I have no idea what's causing this problem.

http://puu.sh/3TAFi.png